# Changing vertical spacing before and after \equation

Tags: spacing, equations

I use

```
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
```

to achieve the goal stated in the question title. However I am not sure where I have to put it. I am using \include or \input to work on several parts of my .tex. Putting it in the preamble of the masterfile doesn't affect another included tex, but I also don't want to add the code above to every single .tex that I "\include". Another problem I have is that I am uncertain about whether this might affect other spacings I don't want to change.

Comment: This is strange - I don't have any code resseting code after it, but still does change apparently. Thank you though, I must be missing something!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have found it to be working when the code above is put immediately after \begin{document}, but not working when put immediately before \begin{document}. Does \begin{document} reset the code?

Comment: they are reset whenever you use `\normalsize` for example the expected behaviour is to define `\normalsize` to mach your spacing to match the font, it doesn't just set the font it sets display and list settings as well as baselineskip (\begin document does \normalsize)

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These settings are not reset on `\input` or `\include` but are reset by most size change commands such as `\normalsize` or `\large` as these reset all the major spacing to be compatible with the requested size. Note in particular `\begin{document}` does `\normalsize` which for 10pt article is:

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
```

So if you are defining a class with tight spacing (or a package to modify the spacing of the sandard classes) you should redefine `\normalsize` rather than setting these lengths directly.